# FiddlerCore with Python for .NET

Tags: python, .net, python.net, fiddlercore

I'm trying to make FiddlerCore work with Python for .NET, but I've got a "mscorlib recursive resource lookup bug". Here's code:

```
import os
import sys
import clr
clr.AddReference("FiddlerCore")
import Fiddler

def printReq(sesion):
    print(session)

Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = False
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += printReq
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, Fiddler.FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default)

while(True):
    if raw_input("exit? ") == "y":
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown()
```

Comment: This issue is tracked here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/452